# What does it mean, "out of fresh water"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Nimitz: That was Washington. They've intercepted several Japanese
>   messages claiming that the target of their upcoming attack is **out of
>   fresh water**.

It sounds very identical to idiom called "fresh out of something". I find this line in Midway 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fresh water" distinguishes from "salt water" as you would find in the ocean. It could also mean "drinkable water" rather than just non-salty water (i.e. tap water rather than river water).

Google tells me "Midway" is a film about naval battles in the Pacific. Based on that, I would hazard a guess that the line means that the target of the upcoming attack is another ship, and the ship does not have any drinkable water left on board.